# What do you call a CGI version of an actor?

Tags: word-request

For example, in the movie Star Wars Carrie Fisher played Princess Leia, but because she was not as young as she used to be, they used a CGI version of her. What do you call the CGI version of an actor? Is there a particular word for it?

Here's an example sentence:

> Disney used a ___ of Carrie Fisher in 10 other Star Wars movies.

Comment: Perhaps a virtual image?

Comment: Yes, what you just used. *Disney used a **CGI version** of Carrie Fisher in 10 other Star Wars movies . . .*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGI can be used as a noun adjunct like this:

> Disney used a **CGI Carrie Fisher** in 10 other Star Wars movies.

It's short, specific, and it's something people definitely say. Here are some examples:

- > [VLOG: LucasFilm Confirmed No CGI Carrie Fisher](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VG_CtO9grPY)
- > On top of all the action, special effects, explosions, brief clips of fight scenes, and of course, a CGI Samuel L. Jackson who looks way better than actual young Samuel L. Jackson, this trailer does one very important thing… give the audience a better idea of what Captain Marvel will be about. —[New Captain Marvel Trailer… Oh Yes It’s Good](https://nerdbot.com/2018/12/04/new-captain-marvel-trailer-oh-yes-its-good/)
- > [Watch new ‘Pirates of the Caribbean 5’ trailer, featuring CGI Johnny Depp as young Jack Sparrow](https://www.nme.com/news/film/pirates-of-the-caribbean-5-trailer-young-jack-sparrow-johnny-depp-1999412)

Answer (score 2):

The phrase that you use in your question is correct and clear

> Disney used a CGI version of ...

You could also use "virtual"

> A virtual Carrie Fisher

But this is less explicit and perhaps less clear.